# Replace sequential repeating tags with one of that tag in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to replace multiple sequential `<br>` tags with just one `<br>` tag using Ruby.

For instance:

```
Hello
<br><br/><br>
World!
```

would become

```
Hello
<br>
World!
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *could* do this with a regular expression, like:

```
 "Hello\n<br><br/><br>\nworld".gsub(/(?im)(<br\s*\/?>\s*)+/,'<br>')
```

To explain that: the `(?im)` part has options indicating that the match should be case-insensitive and that `.` should match newlines.  The grouped expression `(<br\s*\/?>\s*)` matches `<br>` (optionally with whitespace and a trailing `/`) possibly followed by whitespace, and the `+` says to match one or more of that group.

However, I should point out that in general it's not a good idea to use regular expressions for manipulating HTML - you should use a proper parser instead.  For example, here's a better way of doing it using [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/):

```
require 'nokogiri'

document = Nokogiri::HTML.parse("Hello
<br><br/><br>
World!")

document.search('//br').each do |node|
    node.remove if node.next.name == 'br'
end

puts document
```

That will produce output like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><p>Hello
<br>
World!</p></body></html>
```

(The parser turns your input into a well-formed document, which is why you have the DOCTYPE and enclosing `<html><body><p>` tags.)

Comment: I think the `im` needs to go at the end, currently it's not doing anything since it's only acting within its own parenthesis. Also that won't match `<br />`. Thus I think the pattern should be `/(<br[ /|/]?>\s*)+/im` unless I'm screwing up my regex (which is very possible).

Comment: You can toggle on and off options within the regular expression using the `(?im)` syntax.

Comment: I'm not sure it's worth making this example more complex, but I've changed it to match whitespace before the trailing `/`.

Comment: It's been a while since I've done regex, especially in Ruby. Sorry for all the errors. I thought the options toggle only applied within the parenthesis it was in? Or is it the outer ones? Gonna go re-read a Ruby regex tutorial later today to brush up.

Comment: @Andrew: no problem - the modifiers in `(?...)` are turned on until they're turned off again with `(?-...)`.  For example, this matches: `"hEllo" =~ /(?i)He(?-i)llo/`, but doesn't if you change the end of the regex to `lLo/`

Comment: @Andrew: Ah, I see the confusion - I didn't realize that the other syntax you refer to existed.  That's when after the modifiers you have `:` followed by some part of the regex within the parentheses, so the equivalent of my example would be: `"hEllo" =~ /(?i:He)llo/`